# Test whether a promise has been rejected?

Tags: jestjs

I have seem many examples of how to test if a promise is rejected with a certain reason, like below:

```
 it('should reject if no startdate is given', () => {
   expect.assertions(1);
   return expect(MyService.fetch()).rejects.toEqual({
     error: 'Your code message',
   });
 });
```

But how do I write if I just want to test that a promise has been rejected regardless of reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.toBeDefined()` instead of `.toEqual(...)`

EDIT:
You could also use `.toThrow()`, the method which is actually recommended by JEST
As I found later you needed to use async/await to test with this
Here is an example on how to test with them:

```
  it('should test promise reject', async () => {
    await expect(toReject(true)).rejects.toThrow()
  });
```

[Test the code here](https://repl.it/repls/RegalCalculatingMolecule)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you expect a promise to be rejected use the `.rejects`.

   ```
   test('should reject if no startdate is given', () => {
     return expect(MyService.fetch()).rejects.toMatch('error');
   });
   ```
2. You can combine async and await with `.resolves` or `.rejects`.

   ```
   test('should reject if no startdate is given', async () => {
      await expect(MyService.fetch()).rejects.toThrow('error');
   });
   ```